# How to show that the vector value function describes the motion of a particle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

The vector value function is 
$r(t)= (2i+2j+k)+cos(t)((1/\sqrt{2})i-(1/\sqrt{2})j)+sin(t)((1/\sqrt{3})i+(1/\sqrt{3})j+(1/\sqrt{3})k)$
And the particle is moving in the circle of radius 1 centered at the point $(2,2,1)$ and lying in the plane $x+y-2z=2$

Comment: Your question isn't clear, you want to show that it is a circle centered at the stated point?

Comment: No, I want to show that the vector value function, r(t), describes the motion of a particle moving in the circle with radius=1, centered at point (2,2,1), in plane x+y-2z=2

Comment: So you want to show that (a) $\|r(t)-(2,2,1)\|=1$, and (b) the components of $r(t)$ fulfil the equation $x+y-2z=2$. You can check both by simply inserting $r(t)$ and evaluating.